# Using AJAX to pass data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a drop down in PHP. I have some fields from database. Now I have an edit button besides that dropdown in which i want to pass the id the of selected option in dropdown! How can I do this?

```
<tr>
    <td>Base INI File</td>
    <td>
        <select required  name="base_ini_id"  id="base_ini_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select</option>    
            <?php foreach($base as $value) { ?>
                <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?>"><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <?php foreach($customs as $custom) ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo btn_edit('customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/' . $custom->id); ?>
        </td>
        >
</tr>
```

Looks like this :
[image]
As you can see I have a button in a `td` besides the dropdown and I want to link that to the id of the selected option from dropdown using AJAX or jQuery. I have no knowledge of AJAX, but due to requirement I have to implement this.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? At the moment this is a 'write my code for me question'. Here's something to get you started: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: by onchange your select drop down?

Comment: @Gopal yes when i change the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Code. I call sample url from your recruitment. Change as it yours

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <td>
    <select required name="base_ini_id" id="base_ini_id" class="form-control"> 
    <option value="">Select</option> 
    <?php foreach($base as $value) { ?> 
    <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>"><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?></option> 
    <?php } ?> 
    </select> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <a id="edit_link" href=""><button>Edit</button> </a>
    </td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $('#base_ini_id').change(function() {
        var id=$("#base_ini_id").val();
        $("#edit_link").attr("href",  "customer/user/edit/"+id);
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: in my button how will i get the id?

Comment: Yes as mentioned in code i have a button besides the dropdown so which ever value i select from dropdown i want to pass it to my button to edit

Comment: So basically i want to get the value of selected

Comment: i want to get the id of selected option from dropdown

Comment: in btn_edit() function use this one  if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        }

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use id because there may be multiple records in table. For your knowledge id is unique, however you can use class for that.

```
<tr>
    <td>Base INI File</td>
    <td>
        <select required  name="base_ini_id" class="form-control base_ini_id">
            <option value="">Select</option>    
            <?php foreach($base as $value) { ?>
                <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?>"><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span onclick="btn_edit(this);">Edit</span>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Use following JavaScript function to get the selected option

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function btn_edit(control)
 {
   var selected_option = $(control).parent().prev().find('.base_ini_id').val();
   // Use selected option variable to pass data in your php file
  $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/"+selected_option ,
       cache: false,               
       success: function(change)
       {                      
          // Do here what you want...
       }
  });

 }
</script>
```

Here parent() funtion returns parent element of $(control) element.

prev() function return previous element of particular element.

find() function finds class, id or element from specified element.

You can get selected option value in selected_option variable

hope you got me !!

### UPDATE

Use following code

```
<tr>
        <td>Base INI File</td>
        <td>
            <select required onchange="option_change(this);"  name="base_ini_id" class="form-control base_ini_id">
                <option value="">Select</option>    
                <?php foreach($base as $value) { ?>
                    <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?>"><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href = "" class="edit_link">Edit</span>
        </td>
     </tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
function option_change(select)
{
  var selected_val = $(select).val();
  var link = "customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/"+selected_option;
  $(select).parent().next().find('.edit_link').attr('href', link);
}
</script>
```

This will update the href attribute of edit anchor after option change. If you click on edit without select option page will refresh only you can manage something as you want there..

Comment: Where will be my edit button? I want to edit a file to i need to pass the id which file i want to edit so how will i do that

Comment: see my question i have show you how you code give me output, i just shows edit, now edit button takes anchor tag i which i pass the url and the id to edit a record or file

Comment: <span> tag is your edit button. you can use button instead of this.
Now you can run following ajax after get the selected value from dropdown.

Comment: what should i do in my case my button look like this <?php echo btn_edit('customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/' . $id); ?> so first i pass the method then id so how will my id be pass here?

Comment: should i use it like this <td><?php echo anchor(this); ?></td>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104421/discussion-between-rajan-and-vivek-pipaliya).